# Parse push notifications work for emulator, but not real devices

Tags: android, parse-platform, notifications, push

There's been a couple of posts on this topics, but they haven't been helpful for me.

Here are my permissions:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature" android:name="com.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.package.name.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Other stuff:

```
 <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.package.name.PushReceiver" android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.mobiquity.which.VOTE_REQUEST" />
            <action android:name="com.mobiquity.which.VOTE_HAPPENED" />
            <action android:name="com.mobiquity.which.QUESTION_COMPLETE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <!-- app package -->
            <category android:name="com.package.name" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Anyone spot anything wrong or missing?

SOLUTION: I was missing these two permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Rumor has it you may not need GET_ACCOUNTS FOR above 4.0 & 4.1

Answer (score 0):

Several causes for this issue but you are talking about loading the same .apk into the emulator and the device.

Got to
`Settings` ->  `Application manager` -> go to the app and check if `Show notifications` is enabled.

Comment: @SeanThomas even without that permissions the notifications was working on the emulator?

Comment: Yep, that was the case.  Today, I updated the Parse SDK to the latest version which no longer requires GET_ACCOUNTS. Not receiving notifications again...

Answer (score 0):

In version 1.11.0 they removed the GET_ACCOUNTS permission.
Check the [release notes](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android/releases).